# "Head over heels" and "head over feet"

Tags: expressions

Does the expression *head over heels* mean the same as *head over feet*? To be madly in love with someone?

Answer (score 7):

The phrase is definitely ***head over heels*** - to be madly in love with someone typically used to describe a "new love" or "like a new love" condition.

> I just met this girl and I'm *head over heels* in love.

or

> She's lucky! They've been married for 20 years and he's still *head over heels* in love with her.

*head over feet* is never used this way.  In fact as far as I know *head over feet* has no special idiomatic meaning and I can't come up with a situation where those three words would come out of my mouth in that order except for when reading this SE question outloud.

(As an aside- this is where Urban Dictionary and the like must be taken with a grain of salt because it does list *head over feet* to mean the same as *head over heels*, but no native speaker I know would ever utter it.)

Comment: ...except Alanis Morissette?

Comment: Family of related phrases at Maven's Word of the day: ass over teakettle  http://www.randomhouse.com/wotd/index.pperl?date=19960517

Comment: Yeah, well you never can tell with musicians and lyricists.

Comment: @itsadok thank you...i was worried nobody would think of it.

Comment: Maybe it got entered into UD after Morissette's recording?

Comment: "Head over feet" is simply not used. "Head over heels" has history, elegance, and alliteration, none of which apply to "head over feet." The fact that Morissette chose to distort the well-known phrase in no way justifies her version. Let's not forget that she's not exactly an expert in the use of the language. The same song includes a horrible mixed metaphor ("your love is thick and it swallowed me whole") which also includes two clumsy images (love being thick, and love swallowing anything at all). And her song "Ironic" is famous for numerous misuses of the word "ironic."

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg That is simply not true. _Head over feet_ **is** used, though it is much rarer than _head over heels_. As a [quick Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=head+over+feet&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chead%20over%20feet%3B%2Cc0) will show, _head over feet_ started out around the 1930s or 1940s and has been rising in usage ever since—though obviously rising much more rapidly after being made famous by Alanis.

Comment: I believe the use of the phrase in the context of falling in love derives from confusion with "over head and ears in love", i.e. completely submerged.   See:      https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/over_head_and_ears